# Tracking jira epic-subtask relationships in notion. Help needed

Tags: database, jira, notion

I'm trying to solve a problem that's bugged me for the better part of 1-2 days now. I'm trying to sync jira & notion in order to track project progress in a particular way. I've connected jira to my notion doc so i'm able to extract all the project data for a particular board into a notion database ("Issues") and can see all tasks inside that project in my notion doc. So far so good.

What i'd really love to do next, is to be able to have a separate inline database ("Goals") track all the quarterly goals for the team and link those goals to the jira epics associated with the goals and display the number of subtasks & issues (and eventually statuses) that are linked to the epics.

Visually, this is what i'm looking for:

**Goals database**

| Goal | Epic | Number of Tasks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Increase Revenue by 10% | EPIC-1 | 2 |

**Issues (jira synced) database**

| Parent | Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | EPIC-1 |  |
| EPIC-1 | Task-1 | In Progress |
| EPIC-1 | Task-2 | Paused |

Does anyone have any thoughts about how this could be done?